# Cassandra Write failed even when it received the ack from required nodes

Tags: database, spring-boot, cassandra, nosql, datastax

I have cassandra cluster setup with following configurations:-

- Nodes: 5
- DataCenter: dc1
- Replication Factor: 3
- Consistency: `LOCAL_QUORUM`

I got following exception when executed batch statements on table.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during 
write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (3 replica were required 
but only 2 acknowledged the write).
```

Why does it says 3 replica required when consistency is LOCAL_QUORUM(2)?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a trace output for this? This might help to shed more light on the question.

Comment: I got this exception only and during this write operation there was update going on  in Cassandra nodes one after the other.

Comment: Its useful to correlate your application logs with logs from the nodes in the cluster. Check the nodes `/var/log/cassandra/system.log | debug.log` during the same time and see if there is any exceptions showing

Comment: How many DCs do you have? it seems that there is another DC in your setup in which 1 replica is needed to achieve the CL (Consistency Level). So 2 replicas for DC1 and 1 more replica in another DC = total 3.
It also might be that your client's driver is not DC aware... check that as well.